# Analogy for Rayleigh scattering

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, radiation

This morning's eclipse has me looking into Rayleigh scattering. I'm trying to think of a good analogy to explain it to somebody without getting too in-depth into electromagnetism and other subjects... The analogy doesn't need to be completely perfect, just good enough to get the point across.

The best thing I can come up with is this: a toy boat is sitting on a pond. Somebody throws a large rock in the pond next to the boat, creating a big wave. The boat bobs up and down on the wave, gathering upward and then downward momentum. As the wave passes, the boat continues rocking slightly in the water, sending out a new series of tiny ripples much smaller than the original wave.

Can anybody do better?

Comment: I think that's a nice qualitative explanation for elastic scattering. Most people can imagine that or have seen it in reality. It's also easy to demonstrate on a small scale in the bathtub.